# How to disable mingw when using qt6 msvc in cmake

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake, qt6

I'm using cmake msvc in qt, and when I run the project, it has the error below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88vjq.png)

It's weird because I'm runing with msvc instead of mingw

by the way, the default CMakeLists.txt is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(msvc_cmake VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)

set(PROJECT_SOURCES
        main.cpp
        widget.cpp
        widget.h
        widget.ui
)

if(${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} GREATER_EQUAL 6)
    qt_add_executable(msvc_cmake
        MANUAL_FINALIZATION
        ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
    )
# Define target properties for Android with Qt 6 as:
#    set_property(TARGET msvc_cmake APPEND PROPERTY QT_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR
#                 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android)
# For more information, see https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt-add-executable.html#target-creation
else()
    if(ANDROID)
        add_library(msvc_cmake SHARED
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
# Define properties for Android with Qt 5 after find_package() calls as:
#    set(ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android")
    else()
        add_executable(msvc_cmake
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
    endif()
endif()

target_link_libraries(msvc_cmake PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets)

set_target_properties(msvc_cmake PROPERTIES
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER my.example.com
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

install(TARGETS msvc_cmake
    BUNDLE DESTINATION .
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})

if(QT_VERSION_MAJOR EQUAL 6)
    qt_finalize_executable(msvc_cmake)
endif()
```

so I tried to delete the mingw in the path environment, like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxUC7.png)

after deleting, it looks like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xat1M.png)

and I can run successfully.

So my question is "Is there anyway to do this easier? like setting something in the CMakeLists.txt?"

Comment: Is this an open-source version of Qt, or a paid one? Sorry for asking this question: I haven't been in Qt for a few years by now, but back days when Trolltech was the owner of Qt, an open-source version of it was bound to MinGW. This means that one could not simply use open-source Qt with MSVC. The only way was to recompile sources with MSVC

Comment: @pawel_j I think its the open-source version, but I can use the msvc after deleting the mingw without recompiling

Comment: @pawel_j as far as I'm aware that has never and is still not the case